# Find the missing number in the series: 4, 12, 14, 16, ?, 25

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence, sequence

Numbers in the series: 4, 12, 14, 16, ?, 25

Please help me find the missing number in the series above. I have already tried with different sequences but unable to solve this.

Comment: Can you give us some context -- where the question comes from, what other questions if any you've had from the same source, whether there's any context around the question as it stands, etc.?

Comment: @gareth : this was a question that appeared in my exam yesterday. sorry to say, but the question had no more context. and the correct answer is apparently, 26. But I've no idea how did they get that number.

Comment: @user66289 For which subject was this exam? Does the teacher not provide any clues or answers how to solve this?

Comment: @tyui exam was for government post .So there was no chances of giving any clue.

Answer (score 1):

i think the correct answer is

> 24 because in odd position we have +10= 4+10=14 +10=24. in even position 12 16 25, the difference between 16 and 12 is 4=2^2 and the difference 25 16 is 9=3^2. so we have 4 12 14 16 24 25 and then 34 41( 41-25= 16=4^2). I think this is a possibile answer what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I slightly disagree with the other commenter's solutions, I think my pattern is more analytically smooth.
The pattern is:

> digitsum(a_n)^2 = A_n+3
>  For example, digitsum(4)=16
>  Digitsum(14)^2=25

hence,

> digitsum(12)^2=9

Comment: Welcome to PuzzlingSE! When you post your answer, please use the markup guide to hide the solution so others can try solving it without having the answer 'spoiled'.